# Not able to start the delayed job in aws server for rails 2 application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-2

Due to some technical issues, we stopped the AWS server and when we started the server all delayed jobs are showing in the queue, none of the delayed jobs is running on the server, so I need to start the delayed job server. When I used the following command I got some issues which are shown in this picture:

[image: here]

Comment: First manually create the log file path mentioned in error and then get logs and debug them , also make sure log directory has appropriate permission

Comment: As given in the error message install daemons gem